# Disable button when particular table row is selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to disable a particular row button and not all the buttons. I tried using `id` but it only hide the very first row button. Any help would be nice.

**php:**

```
$rowID=1;
while($row = oci_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo '<tr>

  <td>
      <a href="#" rel='.$rowID.' id="buttonq" class="button green ValueDisplay">
            <div class="icon" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;">
                   <span class="ico-edit"></span>
            </div>
      </a>
  </td>

  </tr>';
  $rowID++;
}
```

**js:**

```
<script>
$('.ValueDisplay').click(function()
{
   var getid = this.rel;

   $('#buttonq').css('visibility', 'hidden');
   //document.getElementById('buttonq'+getid+'').style.visibility="hidden";
});
</script>
```

Comment: You give the same id to all a elements. That's a bug.

Comment: @MattThompson `id="buttonq"`

Comment: but that way i can get particular row values. isn't it?

Comment: Apologies. I was thinking you meant record ID :)

Comment: @Matt Thompson i am incrementing id. like `<td id="value'.rowID.'">`

Comment: $('a').attr('rel', getid).hide();

Comment: No, you are updating the rel value. dystroy is talking about "buttonq" to use javascript effectively, you need to make those id's unique as well.

Comment: @user574632 same problem it hides all the values.

Comment: @Matt Thompson i don't know how to to that. Ids are unique.

Comment: oh you are hiding the clicked element? then just $(this).hide();

Comment: Though the other comments about unique ids are correct

Comment: @user574632 post you anser so i can accept it and thanku.

Comment: yes i will try and do it as you guys mentioned.

Comment: Make them unique the same way you did with  the id in rel if you have to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per my comment:
You are hiding the clicked element, so just use:

```
$('.ValueDisplay').click(function(ev)
{
    ev.preventDefault();
    //show all buttons
    $('.ValueDisplay').show();
    // hide this one
    $(this).hide();
});
```

You may as well remove the id, as it is not valid to have duplicate id's and it does not seem to serve a purpose:

```
<td>
  <a href="#" class="button green ValueDisplay">
        <div class="icon" style="margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;">
               <span class="ico-edit"></span>
        </div>
  </a>
</td>
```

Comment: `<td id="OFFbrief'.$rowID.'">'.$row['REMARKS'].'</td>` i am using rowID for that purpose thats why i am doing that.

Comment: Ok, cant see that in you question. Glad i could help

Comment: ok this is working just perfect. how could i show the previous hide button? if i click on other row the button hides but as well show the previous hide button?

Comment: oh you placed `$('.ValueDisplay').show();` this before the hide one. thats good. thankyou so much for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you need the `id` for something else, you can simply toggle the state of a specific row based on which link was clicked.

http://jsfiddle.net/XJVbD/

**PHP**

```
while($row = oci_fetch_array($query))
{
  echo '<tr>
    <td>
      <a href="#" class="button green ValueDisplay">
        <span class="icon" style="display: block; margin-left: 5px; margin-top: 5px;">
          <span class="ico-edit"></span>
        </span>
      </a>
    </td>    
  </tr>';
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.ValueDisplay').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('td').prop('disabled', 'disabled').hide();
});
```

I wasn't entirely clear on whether you're hiding or just disabling. Let me know if the code above isn't what you're after.

**Notes:**

- The user is clicking a link element, so to prevent the page from refreshing, use `e.preventDefault()` in the event handler.
- You have a `<div>` element inside an `<a>` anchor element, which likely won't validate if that matters to you.